# Does Windows 10 support 5.1 audio over USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

Does Windows 10 support 5.1 audio over USB or, is my question kinda nonsense as it's the hardware which will support this or not!

Simply I'm looking at 2 components and would like to know if they can work together. My Windows 10 PC with a USB2.0 socket and a device which will split the audio. http://www.myxlshop.co.uk/j-s-external-sound-card-with-usb-51.html?id=50345220&gclid=CjwKEAjw1qHABRDU9qaXs4rtiS0SJADNzJis52lt2Cd65VkwFDc-wj4r9nsE6FUmd-g0prtGSYITjRoCz3fw_wcB

I know there are other options (external cards, 5.1 audio cards, HDMI) but I'm curious about if it could work with USB (please note, virtual 5.1 is not 5.1!)

The reason for this question is due to Android not being able to do this over USB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Windows 10 or USB cares what-point-what audio you use it for since USB is not an audio interface. You can send any format of audio you want, heck even 9001.1337 over USB if you wanted to.

What matters is the capabilities of the sound card you are using, which in this case claims to be a 5.1 USB sound card, so yes, it will do 5.1

Comment: @Burgi About how USB works? Er...

Comment: I wonder why [Android does](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb.html#androidSupport)  then... Thanks for the answer

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: Because getting USB audio support into Android was a 5-year-long debacle.