# Why Windows 10 not appear to support 5.1 audio

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

This is a follow up to my previous question [Does Windows 10 support 5.1 audio over USB](https://superuser.com/questions/1139890/does-windows-10-support-5-1-audio-over-usb) where I asked if WIndows 10 supports USB audio and the answer is yes.

On my Surface Pro 3 I can use my 5.1 audio decoder via USB to split the audio and it works great. For clarity this means from the tablet -> audio out via USB -> into my decoder -> into the speakers

I have bought a new tablet (Linx 1010b) but the audio does not work via the USB device. I returned to my Surface and it works fine so it's not the audio equipment, it's the tablet (hardware or software). The built in speakers in the tablet play audio fine.

I replaced the Linx 1010b with another Windows 10 tablet and the same issue persists.

The only difference is my Surface is USB3.0 and the other 2 tablets are USB2.0

My question is, can the version of the version of the USB have any impact like this? Or could it be that I've not enabled something.

I've not installed any additional audio drivers because I didn't need to with my Surface Pro. Trying to compare the driver details between the 2 devices suggests (with my understanding) that they are using the same driver any way.

Comment: Its hard to say. It could be the case. Does your surface have a USB 2.0 port too?

Comment: No, but I've now tried it on 2 Windows tablets and a Windows 8.1 laptop - it doesn't work. I've also just tested it on a Surface Pro 3 and a Surface 4 (both with USB 3.0) and it works... so it does suggest this device may require USB3.0 for reasons unknown to me

Comment: Yes. USB3.0 has a higher bandwidth, and the device may require that bandwidth to use 5.1 although strictly speaking it shouldn't need it. I have an old Creative 5.1 USB card that works well with usb 2.0